# Going through lines and doing deletion of a text on particular criteria

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

Is it possible to delete everything after first word in a line using Notepad++? I will need this to go through each line.

Also I would like to know if it is possible to delete only first word in a line, leaving everything behind intact.

Comment: You can select the first word of each line using RegEx like this: `/^\w+\b/`. I'm not sure what language you're using, but once the first word of each line is selected, you can delete it.

Comment: I have tried this regex before by going to CTRL+H-> Mark section and inputting it, however it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should make replacement with Regex. Then in "Find what" you put

```
^(\S+)(.*)$
```

and in Replace with you put

```
$1
```

I assume you separate the first word with space, tab or something similar
For the second task you put

```
$2
```

in "Replace with" instead, but it leaves the first character like space or tab intact, if that's what you want.